# 16: mandatory-script-verify-flag-failed (Script evaluated without error but finished with a false/empty top stack element), code=-26)

Tags: validation, input-script

This is the raw transaction.

```
01000000013a1b3a9209583a8fd345fdf73c80bb22fdf8a0bf1e4fc48252151f6d18b2822901000000020151ffffffff0160a59e7d5100000017a9143dbbda49ccc09591516be148dd966610f254e4bc8700000000
```

Comment: Welcome to SE.Bitcoin. I don't understand what you're asking, there's not even a question mark. Please improve your answer and provide more context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your raw transaction is just completely wrong. Just pushing `OP_TRUE` to the stack does not make any output spendable; you still need to execute the output script. The combined script (input script and output script together) results in a failure/`OP_FALSE` so the input is invalid. Thus the transaction is invalid.

Looking at the output you are trying to spend from, it looks like it is a 3 of 5 multisig, so unless you have 3 of the 5 keys, you can't spend from that output.